# Can an iPhone 3.0 SDK based app continue with data processing while answering a phone call?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, multitasking

I always thought that once I choose to receive a phone call my aplication is shut down.
Now I hear of some SDK 3 based application that keeps sending location data while a phone call is being answered?

Is it possible? (Not a jail broken iPhone)

How?

Answer (score 0):

When a call is in progress and one or the two calling parties are being carried in moving transport the system has to inform the network through the mast or antenna that the person or device is moving from one cell to another and then the system can switch the call in progress to the next cell being approached in the direction of travel. When a more direct or non-cell network is in use then the antenna has to send or receive the signal sometimes at different horizontal angles to a series of geographical positions and if necessary pass the call to a later antenna. Fast moving transport sometimes beats the system. In the situation you describe the location could be sent because the phone user has selected a 'send my position' or 'position locator' facility on their phone or it is a phone for officials, officers or children who may be at risk.

Comment: My question wasn't about the mechanics of the location services but more about multitasking under iphone sdk 3. Is it possible for a non jail broken app to do any kind of processing (e.g. sending its location to a web service) while a call is in progress